# How to encode numeric QRCode correctly?

Tags: c, encoding, qr-code

I'm using [libqrencode](http://fukuchi.org/works/qrencode/manual/index.html).
I want a QR Code with **version 1** (21x21) and **ECC Level H**. According to http://www.qrcode.com/en/about/version.html I can have 17 Numerics. So I do:

```
QRcode *result;
QRinput *input = QRinput_new2(1, QR_ECLEVEL_H);
unsigned char *data = new unsigned char[17];
for(int i = 0; i < 17; i++) {
    data[i] = 0;
}

QRinput_append(input, QR_MODE_NUM, 17, data);

result = QRcode_encodeInput(input);

int idx = 0;
printf("%d\n", result->width);
for(int i = 0; i < result->width; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < result->width; j++) {
        if(result->data[idx] & 1) {
            printf("%d", 1);
        } else {
            printf("%d", 0);
        }
        idx++;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

But whaterver my data is, my program returns the same output.
What i'm missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I submit an issue for there github and got the answer very quickly https://github.com/fukuchi/libqrencode/issues/33#issuecomment-24997167
The issue is my data init here:

```
unsigned char *data = new unsigned char[17];
for(int i = 0; i < 17; i++) {
    data[i] = 0;
}
```

should be:

```
unsigned char *data = new unsigned char[17];
for(int i = 0; i < 17; i++) {
    data[i] = '0'; //here
}
```